# Parameterize (like in Rails) a Column in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, url, query-string

I am looking for a way to simulate Ruby on Rails' `parameterize` method in Postgres.

I have a query that gets the job done but I feel there must be a better way.

For my task, I need to set a field (`mktg_url_slug`) to the parameterized version of the `name` column.

For example:

"2020 Nordic (Helsinki) Winner Circle Q4"

would turn into:

"2020-nordic-helsinki-winner-circle-q4"

My query:

```sql
-- Ghetto parameterize:
update events set 
mktg_url_slug = 
lower(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(name, '(', ''), ')', ''), '.', ''), ',', ''), ' ', '-')) 
where begin_date >= '2017-01-01' and mktg_url_slug is null;
```

Comment: Don't forget about [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html) which avoids all this nested `replace()` stuff.

Comment: I've been a software developer for 25+ years but I've always had a hard time with regex syntax for some reason. So I usually avoid it unless I'm copy-pasting someone else's work. :)

Comment: Sounds like you're over-due for at least a basic understanding. Regular expressions are extraordinarily powerful and don't have to be that complicated.

Comment: Haha, you are right @tadman. Time to dust off that old online regex tutorial I keep saying I'm going to finish. For the longest time my brain didn't want to accept jQuery syntax either. But I overcame that.